# The use of 'otherwise' in a sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

For some reason I cannot understand the following sentence

"Unless we mutually agree otherwise in writing, you will..."

Is this mean that agreement must be in writing or that it does not have to be in writing (verbal)?

Comment: *Unless we mutually agree to a different course of action, and we put that agreement in writing, you will . . .*

Comment: ah 'otherwise' isnt referring to whether being written or not but referring to what was agreed upon. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

**otherwise** is the object in the sentence. "we agree" is the root phrase, with "in writing" as an (unmodified( dependent clause. *What* "we agree" upon, in this case, is something *not already in the contract*  --> something other than what was stated --> something "otherwise" --> otherwise

Clumsily phrased, especially considering contractual context, for this interpretation.